# Using deprecated x86_32 instructions in 64 bit mode

Tags: x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture

Not sure whether this is a dumb question or there is a clever trick involved here.

I want to use x86_32 'into' ( exception on int overflow ) instruction for a debugger I am writing for fun. I see this instruction was never really mainstream and got deprecated in x86_64. I want to perform int overflow checks in my program at runtime ( I am building this functionality on top of a dynamic binary instrumentation framework ) for x86_64.

1. Is there any way to use this instruction for bounds checking on x86_64 by using some trick ?
2. I dont have liberty to recompile programs so all compiler related flags are ruled out. I have infrastructure to generate runtime code though.
3. I don't want to implement this bounds checking in software ( I have my own reasons ) and want to leverage hw features.

NOTE: I am aware of new Intel MPX instructions which can be used for bounds checking, but these are not widespread yet.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: It didn't just get 'deprecated', it was entirely removed for 64-bit code.  You simple check the OF flag with the JO and JNO instruction.  There's little point in asking this question if you can't compile programs.

Comment: Yes, you are right this instruction is altogether removed from x86_64. I can't recompile but I can do runtime code generation. And thanks for the input, I see what I can do with these.

Comment: One more query on same note, any inputs on how to emulate functionality of bounds instruction on x86_64 ? I am looking into Intel manual but don't see any flag which can help here...

Comment: Just compare the index with the bounds. You can usually treat the index as unsigned in order to make negative indexes "too high".

Answer (score 1):

`INTO` in x64 is deprecated.
This is a **good** thing, lots more instructions (e.g. all of x87) should have been deprecated but sadly have not.

Ever since the first 8086 [and even before](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8008) integer overflow has been handled in the Flags register.

Bounds checking for signed values is done using the `OF` flag, Bounds checking for unsigned values using the `C` flag.

With all the `access violation` checking built into the system there is no need to `INTO` anymore. Your best bet is a write an exception handler.
Maybe ask a question like: "how to catch an exception in x86_64 assembly"?